# How to prevent logo from causing navigation bar from jittering while it's loading

Tags: html, css, navbar, loading, image-loading

I've been trying to find a solution for a while now but none seem to work.

The issue I am having happens when navigating to any and all the pages on the site- it's very annoying.

While I would expect that site images take time to load, this loading affects my navigation bar and the loading of my site's logo.  For the time that it takes each page to load, my site's logo is completely absent- this causes my navigation bar to be shifted all the way up until the logo appears.  This usually takes about a split second but it's also completely dependent on the user's internet connection).

How do I prevent this from happening? This causes my entire site to "bounce" when navigating, with all the content being shifted up for a brief moment while the logo is absent.

[image: Appearance while the webpage is loading]

[image: Loaded webpage]

Comment: 1- Use a pre-loader / 2- Lazy-Load the images / 3- Make sure the images are progressive JPEGs (I recommend combining 2 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your image tag an absolute height attribute. This will make the browser keep the img tag the height it should be and allow the elements to load in the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try tweaking a loader to have the page load only when all of the elements in the page have loaded. Something as simple as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>

<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

With some modification, can help the UI experience!

Source: [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5)

Hope it helps!